# Ho do I got about solving this integral for a variable?

Tags: integration

I am currently in an introductory course to quantum mechanics. For a homework problem we are given the wave function

$$ \Psi(x) = \frac{N}{x^2 + a^2}, a > 0 $$

and asked to normalize it ("Solve for $N$"). To do so, we impose the condition

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\Psi(x)|^2\mathrm{d}x=1$$

Thus the problem is to find the value of $N$ that satisfies the condition

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left| {\frac{N}{x^2 + a^2}} \right| ^2\mathrm{d}x=1$$

But I am not sure how to start to solve this type of problem. The professor mentioned using a tool such as Mathematica, so I attempted to find a solution using Wolfram Alpha online. After a two step process ([One](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20for%20n%20in%20the%20equation%20integral_(-%E2%88%9E)%5E%E2%88%9E%20(n%2F(x%5E2%20%2B%20a%5E2))%5E2%20dx%20%3D%201), [Two](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%201%2F2%20(1%2Fa%5E2)%5E(3%2F2)%20n%5E2%20%CF%80%20%3D%201%20for%20Re(a%5E2)%3E%3D0%20%E2%88%A8%20a%5E2%20not%20element%20R%20%3D%200%20for%20n)) I found $N$ to be

$$ N = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \sqrt{a^5}$$

Though this value does not satisfy the condition imposed.

**How else might I go about solving this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that
$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{|N|^2}$$

I'll use contour integration to evaluate that integral. First, notice that
$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^2}\,dx$$

Consider 
$$\int_C f(z) dz$$
Where $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z^2+a^2)^2}$, $C$ is the upper semi-circle parametrized by $z=x,  x\in [-R,R]$ and $z=Re^{i\theta}, \theta\in[0,\pi]$. Then

\begin{align}
\int_C f(z)\,dz &= \int_{-R}^R \frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^2}+\int_0^\pi \frac{iRe^{i\theta}}{(R^2e^{2i\theta}+a^2)^2}\,d\theta
\end{align}
As $R\to\infty$, the first integral approaches $2I$, and the second integral vanishes. Now, by the Residue Theorem and because $f(z)$ has a pole of order 2 at $z=ia$ inside our contour,

\begin{align}
\int_C f(z)\,dz&= 2I \\ &= 2\pi i\text{Res}(f(z),z=ia) \\ &= 2\pi i \lim_{z\to ia} \frac{d}{dz} (z-ia)^2 \frac{1}{(z-ia)^2(z+ai)^2} \\ &= 2\pi i \lim_{z\to ia} \frac{d}{dz}  \frac{1}{(z+ai)^2} \\ &= -4\pi i \lim_{z\to ia} \frac{1}{(z+ai)^3} \\ &=\frac{\pi}{2a^3} \\ I&=\frac{\pi}{4a^3}
\end{align}
Then,
$$|N|=2\sqrt{\frac{a^3}{\pi}}$$

Answer (score 1):

We can actually only compute $|N|$, since multiplying $N$ by a unit complex number won't change anything, but you're expected to compute the unique value $N>0$ that will work. It's just $I^{-1/2}$ with $I:=\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^2}$. If you want a hint for that integral, substitute $x=a\tan t$.